# Let $\{x_k\}$ be a convergent sequence in the metric space $(X, ρ)$, with limit $\lambda$ say. Show that $\{x_k\}$ is also a Cauchy sequence.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{x_k\}$ be a convergent sequence in the metric space $(X, ρ)$, with limit $\lambda$ say. Show that $\{x_k\}$ is also a Cauchy sequence.

I'm not sure how to begin such as proof, could I have a hint.

Comment: Can you write down the definitions for both things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\{x_k\}$ is a convergent sequence,

$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N} s.t. n\geq N \Rightarrow \rho(x_n,\lambda)<\epsilon$

What we want to prove is that,

$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N'\in \mathbb{N} s.t. m,n\geq N' \Rightarrow \rho(x_n,x_m)<\epsilon$

Now, for any $\epsilon >0$, if we had $ m,n\geq N$, we have $\rho(x_m, \lambda)<\epsilon/2$ and $\rho(x_n,\lambda)<\epsilon/2$.

By the triangle inequality, what can we say about  $\rho(x_m , x_n)$?

Can you get from here?